# How should I interpret down-votes and putting on-hold for this question of mine?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on meta, and requested a clarification for an ambiguous part of the [canonical post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/2651073) on what to do if you get banned... (which I think should be very clear because of its importance) My question was https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284017
Many down-voted it and one user linked me to a more useful answer for a similar problem.

However after I discussed it in a chat room, they noticed the ambiguous point I was trying to convey and posted this question on the point they totally had ignored [So you got banned? No problem, just create a new account (or not?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284271/so-you-got-banned-no-problem-just-create-a-new-account-or-not) (this time with many up-votes!!!)

Anyway I don't want to argue about it but I have frequently hear that votes are as user wish, they are helpful, they shouldn't be misunderstood, they are not biased, they just want to help you....

When we think to the mission of website, I try to give the right to them and don't count myself an exception. I say that is the best way, they can vote as I do, there should be something wrong with my question and I should learn something from this happening.

But still can't get the purpose of them. it was ignored and down-voted while the other post which discuss the point I addressed got that importance, I don't want to say they are identical, but the gap between votes is too high. Does the one who asks make a bias here...should I always have good assumptions?...

I don't want to complain just like to learn, what can I learn from that?

Comment: It could be simply so, people interpret it as circumventing the ban and react negatively. Meta questions **may** be downvoted if people disagree with the premises.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢѸ́ФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ, I know but they could clear or discuss that guide I brought, anyway one may do that and use one question per week and they allow it, then why not with the same email... its important and should be more clear I think, I agree that there is something strange in it.

Comment: @Р̀СТȢ: What's with that name -.-

Comment: @Cerbrus I did not know you could click on name after typing `@`, I found it out when I saw that name :p

Comment: I think people around here just get mad when users get banned then create a new account. I think your question is fine, you found something saying this is okay from a mod. You just asked why it is that way. If you hang around Meta enough you will start to see what sorts of things get downvoted into oblivion here, it's as much about "meta culture" and popular opinion here as it is about whether or not your question was bad, or even if people agree or disagree with you. It's not always possible to "disagree" with a question, as is the case with yours. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Though I did not vote one way or another and it was closed when I found it: Your previous meta question was hard to understand. That's not a huge problem in and of itself, but you then _started to argue in the comments against clarifying your question._ Servy's very first comment on your other question told you that the question was unclear- A comment or two before that was the same. Not only did you not clarify your question, which probably would have kept it open, you answered completely differently from what you appeared to be asking. Thus- Your question was unclear.

Comment: @Kendra, You can note to my current update, there is this message http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284271 by one who got my point, my complain even in my first comment was why you don't clear the part I addressed, why they didn't try to check and understand it? Yes I should be clear but they also should think what a message is pointing. its mutual, and finally yes suppose I am a bad-tempered man (while I am not) but you are professional, shouldn't you vote the content not the asker?

Comment: @Ahmad I'm not going to explain more past this comment- I don't think Bart necessarily understood what you were asking. In fact, it seems he's asking _why_ we would allow this instead of _how_ do we do this. The answer you posted to your question shows that you were looking for how to complete this, not why it's an option. As for _"why you don't clear the part I addressed"_: Nobody understood what you were asking there- It took me a few minutes of looking at it to realize you wanted clarification on what that part of the answer means. "Clear" in the way you used it makes little sense. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In that sentence, it almost looks like "remove" or something similar. What you meant was "clarify." I'm assuming you're a non-native English speaker, which is completely understandable. That said, you still really have to try your best to convey your point. This question, for example, is much clearer as to your meaning, and was probably mainly downvoted for coming across a little on the ranty side. (Not saying it is a rant, just that it has elements of one.) Also note: As to "they should also think...", it is your job as the asker to be as clear as possible. Not answers, you as asker.

Comment: this is long known issue: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773) (it's particularly prominent at MSE/MSO sites where gang voting seems to be popular)

Comment: @gnat and again gnat, thank you !! all the day I was thinking so its an open website with millions of visitors, they can not be biased, ... my god why such differences happen! what is wrong !! now the curtain fell everything got clear :).

Comment: I think this is a question for psychologist. Humans are complex beings. Do not expect that they will vote for purely merotorical reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Here on MSO, voting can have several meanings. As on all the other SE websites, downvoting could mean that your question lacks resource, is poorly formatted etc. Upvotes could mean that your post shows effort, is a good question in general, etc.

However voting can also show if someone agrees or disagrees with your question, and in your case I *think* that people just disagree with your question, as the question looks like it is about circumventing a ban - which is of course also fixable by editing your previous questions. Your post however is not about circumventing a ban, simply because it was build into the system (as you explained in your post). So therefore nobody but the voters themselves, could explain their vote.

Remember there are no `reasons` needed to up- or downvote someone, if you think a question or answer deserves a vote, you may cast it for whatever reason you want (serial voting will be reversed though).

Comment: true there is no reasons for it, but when we suppose good faith, we expect something in question is wrong and should be corrected. I think I face a professional site which vote have some useful meaning otherwise can't learn anything if it happens sporadically.

Comment: @Ahmad I know - I was emphasizing that nobody but the voters themselves know exactly why they voted like they did.

Comment: Also I can't get voting on meta to show agreement or disagreement if its not a pull or suggestion. then that makes interpretation even harder, I believe interpreting votes must be easier and they should be more focused.

Comment: @Ahmad They are pretty clear though, just because you don't understand them doesn't make it a problem. Maybe the reason why you were banned in the first place was because your interpretation of votes on your questions were wrong - the truth is, as long as votes are anonymous (which will not change) you will not know why people vote the way they do, unless they clarify it themselves.