# Should I accept a "code-only" answer or an "explanation-only" answer?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

I just posted a question describing a problem, asking an explanation **why I face this problem**, and also a **piece of code** to correct it.

I had two answers, from two different users :

- The first explains me why I face the problem, but without any piece of code to solve it.
- The second gave me a working piece of code, which solves my problem, but without any explanation.

I upvoted both answers because they were helpful, but which answer should I accept ?

**EDIT** I'm not talking about 2 users answering part of the solution, but about an user answering **why** the problem happens without any clue to "how to resolve it ?" and another who resolves it with a piece of code but without any explanation. In the last cast, the problem is solved, but I still don't know why, which is embarassing.

This is more a general topic about "code-**only** answer" vs "explanation **only** answer".

Comment: You could post a self-answer that synthesizes the good aspects of both answers (possibly making it Community Wiki), and accept that.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but I'm reminded of that one time a user told me that they considered code-only answers superior to all others, because they considered explanation to be "chit chat" (quoting the tour) - unnecessary at best, and distracting at worst. They were genuinely upset at the idea that anyone would consider code-only answers poor, or expository answers good, which really threw me for a loop.

Comment: @BoltClock this attitude seems to be [rather widespread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284271/so-you-got-banned-no-problem-just-create-a-new-account-or-not/284437#comment147184_284437)