# Banned from asking a question, feel editing doesn't help due to being buried, so how do I get questions reviewed again?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, post-ban

I have been banned from asking questions due to having a small number of apparently really bad questions (I have tons of other questions, but none of them have more than 1 upvotes (I thought I had one or two that had 4 upvotes, but apparently not), and many have 0 votes).

I have put some effort into improving them, but a lot of the ones that were bad were already answered and I feel as if no one would look at them to see if they were improved.  Also, all the other questions that were not voted down will never be voted up it seems because they are buried by newer questions (perhaps have a tab for featured old questions or something like that would help).

On another note, why do I always get a permanent ban, when I hear there is a temporary ban that can be used too, or question limiter?  I have gotten banned three times now (first time I am at a loss of how to recover, as I was able to recover the other times by improving questions) and each time it was a permanent ban until questions were improved.

Be nice to have a tab with old questions, questions that have been edited, and/or even perhaps a tab with questions with room for improvement.  That way, people are more likely to further review questions down the road.  Also, can someone explain why I never get the temp ban or limited posts and just get banned and what to do now since I can't really improve my questions further?  Does editing a super old question actually help because it seems like it will be less likely to be viewed?

Comment: "some effort into improving them". Two of your three downvoted questions haven't been edited in the last 6 months.... Also, if you edit your 0 voted questions, they'll be pushed to the top of questions, so people will be able to see them.

Comment: I wasn't aware that editing a question that was years old would push it to the top.  Are you sure about that?

Comment: @Patrice I thought so at first, but the "answer" on that post is "fix your posts", whereas this question is more "How do I fix my posts"  Of course that question might be a duplicate as well...

Comment: @cluemein yup. 100%. Edits push it to the top of the "active" questions tab.

Comment: I am also asking about the ban system, why I get perm banned and not throttled, and also proposing a new feature.

Comment: @ryanyuyu he's asking what he can do to his 0 voted posts, how to get out of the ban. The specifics of how to edit his posts might be in order, but first, he'd need to genuinely try.... I'm not sure the amount of editing on his bad/neutral questions REALLY counts as effort for now. Maybe he's stumped in how to edit a specific posts, which would warrant a meta question of its own.

Comment: @Patrice  Didn't know that actually.  Even questions already answered?

Comment: @Patrice yeah good catch.  I kinda gave up with this wall of text.  Way too many "also" and parens within each question.

Comment: @cluemein That is a very intimidating wall of text.  Don't be afraid of line breaks to better organize your ideas.
You are asking like 5 questions in the same post.  That makes your question very broad.  And it also feels like maybe you haven't done enough research, which will attract more downvotes.

Comment: Will edit then.

Comment: @cluemein yup. Any "big enough" action on a post (new answer, edit on the post or any existing answer), will put a post at the top of the "active" questions tab. No other restrictions (that I know of at least)

Comment: By the way, I know that I asked multiple questions here, but they all stemmed from the same situation.  You say its too broad, and I understand that, but discussion ones seem like they could be broad.  And I am proposing features as well, although based on your information, they may be unnecessary due to editted questions going back to the top, which I didn't know.  And I have read a lot of the posts about improving questions.  As I said, I have been banned before and managed to recover.

Comment: * I hear there is a temporary ban that can be used too* - As far as I know, temporary bans are used to deal with bad behavior not bad questions.

Comment: *Be nice to have a tab with old questions, questions that have been edited, and/or even perhaps a tab with questions with room for improvement.* - In your profile under 'Activity' > 'Questions' all of your questions can be sorted by Votes (should help find 0 score questions), Activity (editing will cause questions to go to the top of the list), and Newest (oldest questions at the end).

Comment: @BSMP what I mean is for a tab to go where you have New, featured, etc. etc.  Not in your actual profile page.

Comment: You mean a way to see other people's questions sorted that way? You can also sort questions on the main page by Votes, Activity, and Newest.

Comment: In fact, they're currently testing out a new nav where you can add your own tabs so your feature request is something they're technically already testing.

Comment: Could you guys please reopen this (and maybe even reconsidering the down votes), because I think the commenting here actually could be considered answers, as I didn't know much of this stuff, and it wasn't exactly a duplicate of said question, as the information provided was not at that question.

Answer (score 3):

Based on this question...

.... nope. Not got a clue.

---

If you have been banned more than once then then surely you have seen the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)? In particular have a look at [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The whole idea of sites like this is that you have to help us, to help you. If we don't have all the information we need to answer your question - then by definition it is a bad question and will be downvoted.

More to the point, if I see you haven't included all the required information in your question - I'm certainly not going to give my own free time to find it *for* you. I'll just move on the next question, or in some cases downvote and leave a comment as to why. Remember though that there is no requirement to leave a comment for a downvote, so you may not always get that immediate feedback.

Comment: I like that methodology actually, because very few people actually state why, and doing so would help many people.

Comment: @cluemein: A comment can sometimes help a receptive OP, yes. But a downvote helps everyone else, and most potential comments would be very repetitive. It isn't as if the help-center was bad, there was no tooltip on the voting arrows, or the reasons were not elaborated on in minute detail a few hundred times each on meta already...

Comment: and.... the ratio of unreceptive OPs who just start SCREAMING if you dare comment means a lot of seasoned users are reluctant to comment, as normally it just means you get into a fight...

Comment: @Patrice Exactly! I can't count how many comments I've flagged because some OP starts cussing people out for downvoting their questions.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ honestly, it's a catch 22... if we comment, we're [insert as many insulting sentences you can think of, hit the Godwin law, and spew general inanities]. If we don't comment, we're "malicious downvoters who downvote for no reason".... I see no good way to weather that storm....

Comment: @Patrice, I completely agree. Honestly, at one point, I was that guy, screaming over downvotes, because I didn't understand the system, now I  take them in stride and try to improve my questions. :)

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ yeah... I don't fully know how to make new users aware of this. It always seems to be a break in how new users see Stack, and how seasoned users see it... I don't know how to make it better to be honest...

Comment: @Patrice I'm not sure there is anything that could be done, like myself, they'll just have to learn. Once people realize that downvotes aren't an personal attack at them and use them as a guide things will change.

Comment: And that's why there is a point based system - so that certain privileges can only be used once you get to know and understand the system.

Comment: oh most definitely. I could just see a great benefit in "breaking" that behavior before it becomes a problem. I see no easy way around it. I just think a lot of potentially good users are being turned off by their first reception. Of course it's their loss, but sometimes I wonder if there's not something we could do better about it... without ever figuring out WHAT we should do :p

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I too used to have a hissy fit before understanding SO's system.  Now, I would appreciate any form of advice, even if it is critical.  As long as it actually contributes something positive, I appreciate any comment suggesting changes to my questions/answers.

Comment: @cluemein Absolutely! Now if we could get everyone to have that attitude :)

Comment: @MacroMan although there are some oddities about the point system:  I have a fairly high reputation, even though I am banned, and I still have all the other priveledges that comes with that rep (reviews of closed posts, edits, etc. etc.)  Basically, its possible for me to be question banned, but able to edit other people's questions, vote down questions, etc. etc.  Although I guess if you are making a positive contribution with those but not your questions, it makes sense.