# Is my account data deleted on account deletion?

Tags: support, deleted-users, personal-data

Does Stack Overflow delete all personal data on account deletion?

Comment: I know some account data is kept because they can identify users who delete their accounts then create new ones to evade question bans. That may just be IP address based though.

Comment: @AndrewT. Users are actually hard deleted, but there is a mimimal set of information that is saved, though I'm not sure which information exactly is kept on deletion.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks, I stand corrected. I also deleted my previous comment since apparently there's a glaring typo (it should read "I have**n't** found any reference")

Comment: What do you consider personal data? For instance, if the fact is recorded that two separate questions were asked by the same now-deleted user, does that count? (Considering that the complete list of all questions that were asked may well contain enough to identify some people, even if individual questions aren't.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Account deletion doesn't remove the part of data necessary to maintain the [anti-recidivism system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/anti-recidivism-system/info):

> The system that deals with users who request deletion in order to evade restrictions that are placed on their accounts at the time of deletion...
>
> We log data on such accounts at time of deletion, which is then referenced should a new account from the same individual be created. If the user was suspended at the time of deletion, then the new account will inherit the remainder of the original suspension. If the user was blocked from posting questions at the time of deletion, then the recreated account will be restricted to posting only one question per week until the quality of their contributions is demonstrated...

Comment: see also: [So you got banned? No problem, just create a new account (or not?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285981/839601)