# A better way to handle plagiarised posts

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

How we handle plagiarism has been on my mind for a while and I feel that the way we do things at the moment seems to be less than optimal. Plagiarised posts seem to get left on the site for too long.

With plagiarism there are two goals:

1. Get the information copied from elsewhere either properly attributed or deleted.
2. Stop people plagiarising.

The first goal is relatively easy to achieve. If you find a plagiarised post check the licencing on the source and if it allows copying with attribution just edit the reference link into the post. That's it. There's nothing more you *need* to do.

If the licence doesn't allow copying with attribution then flag the post so that we can delete it. In the past I have said that it's the copyright owners responsibility to request that copied material be taken down, but plagiarism is different to a copied image (for example) and needs to be dealt with as soon as it's found.

If you discover that the same user has plagiarised more than this one post then raise a flag as the moderators can then determine whether there's anything more we need to do.

One concern has been that when a plagiarised post garners sufficient up-votes the user gets to "keep" the reputation if the post is eventually deleted. However, our goal as moderators is to stop the plagiarism. Hopefully we can do this with a comment on the post or, in more serious cases, a moderator message. If they reform, the fact that the user gets to keep some "ill-gotten" reputation is really a side issue.

However, if steps fail and the user continues to plagiarise then we can take more drastic action by suspending the user or even deleting their account.

In cases where all, or nearly all, of a users posts are plagiarised then we should probably be deleting their account pretty much straight away. They are clearly not interested in participating in our community.

What I'd like to ensure is that these things happen as efficiently as possible with the minimum number of flags being raised.

So, is what I propose workable?

Comment: I don't understand which parts of this post describe the status quo and which are a proposal to do things differently.

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: The third last paragraph is the proposal. Everything else describes the status quo.

Comment: How would this proposal handle a **single author** who employs **different pseudonyms on SE and his/her personal blog** while posting the same information? — Personally, I am not in favour of over-policing.

Comment: I have a small but important complaint about your wording: [plagiarism as defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) has nothing to do with licensing. It's an ethical obligation on people who post here, imposed by this community itself (and the Stack Overflow), whenever the content being posted is not original. This obligation is independent of where the content comes from, who originally wrote it, or under what conditions (if any) the author agrees to allow its reuse.

Answer (score 32):

Personally, I don't think we should place the burden on anyone other than the post author to check licensing terms before using off-site material. The handful of us who serve as moderators have too much on our plates, already, and so do those members who are active (and competent) in the review queues.

If something is plagiarized, my personal practice is to delete it immediately, without wasting time looking for copyright notices and terms of use. If a user edits in proper attribution later, I will consider undeleting the post.

## A Counterproposal

My experience is that users who plagiarize once tend to do it nearly all the time. So, when we find a user with one plagiarized post, odds are that nearly all of their other material --- whether that's 1 other post or 100 --- is also plagiarized. Plagiarism is easy, so it's fairly common to find dozens of plagiarized posts by a single author.

The solution I would like to see is an automated plagiarism-checker in the mod tools. It wouldn't need to run on every post on the site, which would be overwhelming. Rather, it would look like this:

1. User flags post as plagiarized by user 1337ContentThief.
2. Mod handles flag and sees that the post really is plagiarized.
3. Mod clicks a link (just like others in the mod tools) labeled "plagiarism check".
4. SO servers queue up a task for each of 1337ContentThief's posts.
5. For each post:

   - 2-3 sample phrases are checked against a major search engine.
   - Any exact matches result in the system raising an automatic flag for further investigation, *with a link to the search engine results*.
6. Any user with 3+ hits also gets flagged as a serial plagiarist.
7. In the event of user deletion/destruction, all of these flags would just be automatically marked as helpful.

In this world, when a mod sees a true, serial plagiarist, the default action would just be "nuke from orbit." I agree 100% with this statement:

> In cases where all, or nearly all, of a users posts are plagiarised then we should probably be deleting their account pretty much straight away. They are clearly not interested in participating in our community.

I think automating all of this investigation would allow us to get rid of these non-productive users (and their misappropriated content) very quickly.

This could, in theory, also be done via scripting (i.e., the mods doing it for ourselves), but it would be better and more reliable if SO sanctioned it.

Comment: In addition to posts, we should look at tag wikis. Those are where I see the most plagiarism.

Comment: does system keep data allowing to identify abuser after their account is destroyed for [anti-recidivism purposes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359486/839601)? Or they can simply re-create account and continue

Comment: @gnat For reasons that are hopefully obvious, we won't reveal exactly what information moderators can see pre- or post-deletion. Let's just say that we're pretty good at finding recidivists (whether plagiarists or other rule-breakers), even when they create new accounts.

Answer (score 25):

***While awaiting for Stack Exchange to develop better tools as [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359762/5292302) by [Ed Cottrell](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2057919/ed-cottrell)***

At [SOBotics](http://www.sobotics.org/) we have developed an algorithm in [Guttenberg](https://stackapps.com/questions/7197/guttenberg-a-bot-searching-for-plagiarism-on-stack-overflow) that can check posts of a user for plagiarism.

However the current problem is that the search engine we use (Google) only allows 100 free calls x day and currently we can only compare with other posts on Stack Overflow. This command can only be executed by a RO or a moderator, for an example output see [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=39886721#39886721).

What can be done to improve this method:

- Better search API on Stack Exchange (avoid problem of using external search engine with quota limit)
- Improved code to find what content in post to search on
- Continue with "related" search on Stack Overflow when quota on external search engine is expired

Conclusion any moderator is free to run the command `@gut checkuser <iduser>` in the [SOBotics room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics), the result will have limitation of quota but often can find the most obvious plagiarism fairly quick.

Comment: This is very cool. Thanks for suggesting it!

Comment: Note that the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room is sometimes asked by moderators to inspect and flag plagiarized posts from certain userprofiles.

Answer (score 14):

I think the demands that a full investigation of plagiarism put on a moderator are entirely unreasonable. Essentially you have to view every single post of the user and figure out if it is copied from somewhere else. My experience is with much smaller sites than SO, and already there this was nothing that could be done without spending a completely unreasonable amount of moderator time for users that had more than a handful of contributions.

In my opinion, once a user has been shown to have clearly plagiarized several posts, the default action should be to destroy the user entirely. It should not be the duty of the moderators to prove every single instance of plagiarism. Once a user has violated the trust of the community, the burden to prove that they're still willing to participate in good faith is on them.

This doesn't mean that moderators should always destroy users that plagiarise. But the quickest action would be to confront the users with the evidence for a few posts, and then challenge them to fix the problem themselves. If they're willing to redeem themselves by fixing their own plagiarised posts, there is a very good chance they will contribute positively in the future. If they're unwilling to do that, I don't think it is unreasonable to just remove their contributions entirely.

This should still be subject to moderator judgement, e.g. in the case of users that seem to mix very good content with plagiarised content. But personally I suspect that the grey cases are much rarer than the black and white ones.